# Need to take temperature from OpenWeather json using spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have wrote java spring boot application to take temperature from openweatherapi. i am getting full json code and from that i need only temperature value.

How to parse and get.

SpringBoot application with ResponseEntity response

```
@PostMapping("temperature")
    ResponseEntity<?> getTemperaturebyLocationCoordinates(@ModelAttribute TemperatureBean tempBean) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate
                .getForEntity("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + tempBean.getLatitude() + "&lon="
                        + tempBean.getLongitude() + "&APPID=" + apikey + "&units=metric", Object.class);
        return response;
    }
```

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 80.14,
        "lat": 13.36
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 31,
        "pressure": 1005,
        "humidity": 70,
        "temp_min": 31,
        "temp_max": 31
    },
    "visibility": 4000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.1,
        "deg": 300
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 75
    },
    "dt": 1565012771,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 9218,
        "message": 0.0132,
        "country": "IN",
        "sunrise": 1564964708,
        "sunset": 1565010350
    },
    "timezone": 19800,
    "id": 1259290,
    "name": "Puduvayal",
    "cod": 200
}
```

i want only temp: 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a class containing a nested class that represents the received JSON.

OpenWeatherResponse.class

```
public class OpenWeatherResponse {

    private Main main;

    // constructor and getters ommitted
}
```

Main.class

```
public class Main {

    private int temp;

    // constructor and getters ommitted
}
```

Then replace the entity in the rest call

```
final String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + tempBean.getLatitude() + "&lon="
                    + tempBean.getLongitude() + "&APPID=" + apikey + "&units=metric";
ResponseEntity<OpenWeatherResponse> response = restTemplate
            .getForEntity(url, OpenWeatherResponse.class);

final int temp = response.getBody().getMain().getTemp();
```

This is the simplest way.

You can also write a custom serializer but that takes much more effort.

Comment: The method getMain() is undefined for the type OpenWeatherResponse i am getting this error

Comment: did you read my comment in the class? i omitted the getters, you need to implement the getters yourself, because i didn't type them out.

Comment: When i try to create getters and setters for Main.class i am getting this error

The operation is not applicable to the current selection. Select a field which is not declared as type variable or a type that declares such fields